# Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null, because of my component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using Vue.Js I have a small issue with `srcObject` doesn't work because Im injecting my code inside my modal component as you can see. ( but it works if i remove the `<modal></modal>`

The error exactly in : `videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;`

**This is the error message I get in my console:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null
```

**This is my code :**

```
<template>
  <div class="float-right">
    <button
      class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
      @click="showModal = true"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#addContact"
    >
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Scan
    </button>
    <modal size="modal-sm" title="Scan a Business Card" v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
      <div>
        <div id="stream">
          <div>
            <video ref="video" id="video" width="1024" height="576" autoplay></video>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"
              style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px"
              id="snap"
              v-on:click="capture()"
            >Capture</button>
          </div>
          <canvas ref="canvas" id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="c in captures" :key="c.id">
              <img v-bind:src="c" height="50" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
      </div>
      <template v-slot:footer>
        <button
          type="button"
          @click="$emit('close')"
          class="btn btn-default"
          data-dismiss="modal"
        >Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">SCAN</button>
      </template>
    </modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getAPI } from "../../axios-api";
import Modal from "../../components/Modal.vue";

export default {
    components: { Modal },
    data: () => ({
        showModal: false,
        video: {},
        canvas: {},
        captures: []
    }),
    mounted() {
        this.initVideo();    
    },
    methods: {
        initVideo() {
            this.video = this.$refs.video;
            if (
                "mediaDevices" in navigator &&
                "getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices
            ) {
               // const streamElem = document.getElementById('stream').appendChild('video')
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
                const videoPlayer = document.querySelector("video");
                videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
                videoPlayer.play();
            });
                console.log("init...");
            } else {
                alert("Livestream currently unavailable.");
            }
        },
        capture() {
        this.canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
        // this.canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        // this.canvas = document.getElementById("galleryCanvas");
        var context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        this.captures.push(this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The error is letting you know that `videoPlayer` is null so you can't assign a property on it. Why is it null? `document.querySelector` failed to find it. Maybe on the mount lifecycle hook the element is not yet in the DOM or is hidden by a v-if?

Comment: Looking through again, it looks like <video> will only be in the DOM if `showModal` is true, which on mount is `false`. That appears to be the cause of your null reference error.

Answer (score 2):

The model is bind to the showModal variable. Model will only appear when this value is true but by default the value is set to false. Therefor, you have to first set this value to true before appending any element to the modal.

```
if(your condition is true){
   this.showModal = true;
   // write further logic to append the video element
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example using my code please

Comment: See the comment I left on your main post. `showModal` is `false` when your `initVideo` function is called. Therefore `document.querySelector('video')` will return nothing because it is not present in the document.

Comment: Dear, What exactly you wanna achieve. Are you trying to play a video inside a model through API response or prop ?

Comment: just i want to play video :) @MuhammadAtifAkram